# Trying to edit specific row in SQLiteDatabase, but it updates every item in the database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

As the title, I am trying to update a specific data stored in SQLiteDatabase, but it updates every item in it.

What I am trying is making a note taking app. So far it saves what I want to save properly but when I try to edit a note, the problem comes.

It changes all the saved notes when I press the edit button, including the note I wanted to edit.

The note is defined as MemoItem object i.e. MemoItem memoItem = new MemoItem(), and has following variables: String savedTime, memo, and category.

When I tap the note I want to edit it takes saved values successfully but yeah.

And just in case it is needed, here are the things that are declared in my SQLiteOpenHelper class:

```
public class MemoListDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MemoListDB.db";

    public static class MemoEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "entry";

        public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY = "category";
        public static final String COLUMN_SAVED_TIME = "savedTime";
        public static final String COLUMN_MEMO = "memo";
    }

    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE " + MemoEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        MemoEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
        MemoEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORY + " TEXT," +
        MemoEntry.COLUMN_SAVED_TIME + " TEXT," +
        MemoEntry.COLUMN_MEMO + " TEXT )";

}
```

I made a updateNote() method inside the Helper Class:

```
public void updateNote(MemoItem memoItem) {

    if (memoItem == null) {
        return;
    }

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(MemoEntry.COLUMN_MEMO, memoItem.memo);

    db.update(MemoEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, "_id=" + MemoEntry._ID, null);

}
```

And the edit button is inside a Fragment called MemoFragment.

The overridden onClick method has another method named updateMemoOnClick() in it, which I made.

When the button is clicked it will make a new MemoItem object that has category, memo, and saved time that user put in and pass the object to updateNote() method above:

```
private void updateMemoOnClick() {

    MemoItem memoItem = new MemoItem();
    memoItem.memo = memoEditText.getText().toString();
    memoItem.category = selectedBodyPartTextView.getText().toString();
    memoItem.startedTime = startTimeTextView.getText().toString();

    memoListDbHelper.updateMemo(memoItem);

}
```

Why is my SQLite update() updating all the items the database has?

Can anyone please help? I have been on this problem for the half of the day already. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> Here you making the mistake

```
  db.update(MemoEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, "_id=" + MemoEntry._ID, null);
```

replace `MemoEntry._ID` with your row id . like `memoItem.id`

```
 db.update(MemoEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, "_id=" + [row id should be here], null);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "[row id should be here]"? I am totally new to SQLite and I don't really get what you mean there.

Comment: You have to pass the particular primary key _ID as Row id

Comment: Pass this memoItem.id

Comment: Thanks, but my MemoItem object does not have a variable called Id. It has 3 variables only: savedTime, memo, and category. It returns an error saying it cannot resolve symbol ID, or _ID, or Id, or whatever.

Comment: Please take id whenever you retrieved that from the database .

Comment: I am totally new to SQLite, can you enlighten me how I do that?

Comment: If you didn't retrieved the data then how can you able to update it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try different way to update

```
db.update(MemoEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, "_id=?", new String[]
    {String.valueOf(memoItem._ID)});
```

OR

```
db.update(MemoEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, "_id='" + memoItem._ID+"'", null);
```

Comment: My MemoItem object does not have _ID variable, so it returns an error saying it cannot resolve symbol '_ID'. What can I do?

Comment: You have to get '_id' from table while fetching data from table. Or update on the basis of other value.

Comment: So one of the variables is savedTime, I can use it like
db.update(MemoEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, "_savedTime='" memoItem.savedTime+"'", null); ?

Comment: I just have tried this but now it does not change the content at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are displaying the memo entries in a recycler view, so in order to do that you need many MemoEntry objects. You do not need the memoItem object.

You can retrieve the list of entries through a method like this:

```
public ArrayList<MemoEntry> getMemoEntries(SQLiteDatabase db){
    ArrayList<MemoEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor c;

    c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + ENTRY_TABLE, null)
    if(c != null && c.moveToFirst()){
        while(!c.isAfterLast()){
            MemoEntry entry = new MemoEntry();
            entry.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Memo_Entry._ID)));
            entry.setCategory(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Memo_Entry.COLUMN_CATEGORY)));
            entry.setMemo(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Memo_Entry.COLUMN_MEMO)));
            entries.add(entry);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();
    }

    return entries;
```

When you go to edit an entry you can reference the objects id field.
Then you can use the below query once the user saves.

```
db.RawQuery("UPDATE " + MemoEntry.TABLE_NAME + " SET " + MemoEntry.COLUMN_MEMO + " = " MemoEntry.memo + " WHERE " + MemoEntry.COLUMN_ID+ " = " + memoEntry._id ,null);
```

I think the confusion here is that you are putting column names within the MemoEntry object?

It might also be a good idea to update the saved time.

Comment: my MemoItem object does not have a variable named _ID so it returns an error.

Comment: When want to update a note you need to get the key and value pairs. That is the id and the memo. You should add an id field to your memoItem object. When you go to update you can say that the memoItem.id = MemoEntry.id, then you can update as shown above.